# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

```
    DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/"
    HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
    HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"
```

```
    def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
        if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
            os.makedirs(housing_path)
        tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
        housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
        housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
        housing_tgz.close()
```

```
    fetch_housing_data()
```

```
    import pandas as pd
```

```
    def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
        csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path,"housing.csv")
        return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

```
    housing = load_housing_data()
```

I have runned this code but I am getting and error

"TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

"URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>"

Can some one help me solving this code.

Comment: Before running fetch_housing_data can you put in a `print(HOUSING_URL)`? I get the impression the os.path.join might be messing things up.

Comment: Hi Thnk you for the reply. I did what you have said print(HOUSING_URL). I just got "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml2/master/datasets/housing/housing.tgz"